# E-mail Hyperlinks in Word 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word-2010

I was wondering if there's a way to create a hyperlink in a Word 2010 document  that opens an e-mail message and then writes the recipient in the 'To' box but also attaches this document to the e-mail automatically.

This is for a electronic form that we have created, we currently have a link that opens a new message but doesn't attach the document.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know you cant because the Document would have to save on the Drive before they send it. Although I would be interested if this could actually work it would be useful.

Comment: This is very interesting, James. What research have you done so far? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've done a few searches but it's quite hard to search for...i thought maybe some kind of Macro may do it but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: This would require some VBA code as you expect. This [link](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/sendmail.htm) should help you get started.